# How do I access one UserControl's code behind data in a window that is loaded on top the UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, code-behind

I have a WPF application with a UserControl where most of my application lives. In this UserControl I have several different controls that hold user information. When saving the data I create a window that "pops ups" over the UserControl to confirm saving.

In this Window I need some of the data that is in the UserControl to be displayed back to the User as well as saved to the data base.

I have created an object of the UserControl in the Window in order to access the controls as such:

```
    UserControl Ctrl = new UserControl();
```

But this UserControl no longer holds the values I need. Also, the UserControl's constructor takes in optional parameters. I have found that creating a reference in the XAML in order to access the Controls yields the error "The type "UserControlName" does not include any accessible constructors."

I'm doing a Code-behind approach to the application and would like to continue doing that for the most part. But working with dataBinding isn't an issue.

My question is: How does the Window get access to the different values that are held in the Controls or Code-behind of the UserControl so that I can save the necessary data from the UserControl in the Window?

The section of the UserControl's XAML that is necessary is a such:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUserName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,11,0,31" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="txtName_Change"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="cboPasswordExpire" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,20" Height="30"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtUserID" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,20" Height="30" TextChanged="txtUserID_Change"/>
```

The Window uses a DataTable to hold the values and this DataTable (rowSecurityTrans) is used to write to the database. A sample of how the values need to be accessed from the UserControl in the Window is as such (I'm using the 'Ctrl' from the above example of using an object that doesn't work):

```
 rowSecurityTrans["Name"] = Ctrl.txtName.Text;
 rowSecurityTrans["UserID"] = Ctrl.txtUserID.Text;
 strUserName = userEditor.txtUserName.Text;
 rowSecurityTrans["PasswordDuration"] = General.PasswordConverter(Ctrl.cboPasswordExpire.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass it in through the constructor, or update it with properties after the new window is constructed but before it takes focus?

Comment: The window needs to save an arbitrary number of fields. This Window will also be used by other UserControls in later development. So passing the parameters might not be the best way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, the UserControl doesn't have a x:Name.

Comment: So what you need is a generic window that will take whatever data it's given from whatever source and display it, then save it?  You're probably best looking at creating an interface that each of those other classes implement that handle the formatting and saving, and just have the window accept an object of that interface type and call those methods, then display the output...

Comment: Or, on the flip side of that, an interface that each control has to implement that handles their own display of the window and saving of the data...

Comment: @Taegost You gave me an idea with your comment and I think it might be the solution. I don't need to pass the UserControl through the constructor, but I do call the Window through another function. Passing the UserControl there seems to have done the trick. I'll keep testing though to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a generic window that will take whatever data it's given from whatever source and display it.

Your best bet is to look at creating an interface that each of those other classes implement that handle the formatting and saving, and just have the window accept an object of that interface type and call those methods to display the output and save the data

Or, on the flip side of that, an interface that each control has to implement that handles their own display of the window and saving of the data.